# How to target an element that shares its class name with other elements in the same hierarchy?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<div class="menu">
   <ul>
     <li>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Could You please tell me how to target just first ul element with "sub-menu" class as on an example above? Every pseudo-class I know targets both "sub-menu" ul-s at the same time.

Comment: If you are nesting elements like this you should not assign them the same such classname, as semantically they are different. The second sub-menu UL should have a second classname like "sub" or just be different like "sub-sub-menu". This way you can target all sub-menus with an attribute selector for classnames ending in "sub-menu" and still target individual tiers by "(n * sub)-menu". Just a tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option:

```css
ul:not(.sub-menu) > li > .sub-menu {
  ...
}
```